# How to use RegisterType for a class that implements multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Given:

```
public interface IFeedOperations : IOperationsWithPreInstalledData
{
    ...
}

public class FeedOperations : IFeedOperations
{
}
```

How do I use RegisterType for a class that implements `IFeedOperations` AND therefore the `IOperationsWithPreInstalledData` as well?

```
public class FeedsInstaller : IDependencyInstaller
{
    public void Install(IDependencyContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IFeedOperations), typeof(FeedOperations));
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IOperationsWithPreInstalledData), typeof(FeedOperations));
    }
}
```

The current code yields the following error.  And if I remove the second RegisterType then I get no results when I call `container.ResolveAll<IOperationsWithPreInstalledData>()`.

> Component ...Feeds.FeedOperations could not be
>   registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want
>   to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you
>   specify a unique name.

And if I remove the second RegisterType then I get no results when I call `container.ResolveAll<IOperationsWithPreInstalledData>()`.  Castle Windsor doesn't seem to see that a class implementing `IFeedOperations` also implements `IOperationsWithPreInstalledData`.

How can I register my implementing class with Castle Windsor so that it knows my class implements both interfaces -- or rather that either interface can be resolved by my class.

Comment: Do you care if two instances of your class will be created (one for each interface)?

Comment: Would prefer just one instance but I'm not picky in this case.

Comment: Also, `IDependencyContainer` doesn't seem to be any type from Castle. Is that your custom interface?

Comment: yes, that's our type -- we support multiple DI containers.

Comment: So, are you asking how to use your own code? I'm afraid we can't help you with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23062/discussion-between-svick-and-kingdango)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
container.Register(Component.For<IFoo,IBar>().ImplementedBy<FooBar>());
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did to get it working -- figured it out on my own but happy to give you the credit for the answer.  Thank you for responding!

Comment: is it the same as writing `For<IFoo>().Forward<IBar>()`?